# Why do I get "CSRF cookie not set" when POST to Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the error "CSRF cookie not set" returned when trying to POST to a simple test app using the Django REST framework. I've tried it with Django 1.4 and the Django 1.6.2. I am using the Django REST framework v 2.3.13.

I have tried using the `@csrf_exempt` decorator, but it doesn't help.

This is a very simple app, with no user registration / login etc.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

**Update: I have updated my urls.py as shown below and it is now working!!**

Here's my code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from quickstart import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api_add/$', views.api_add, name='api_add'),
)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['POST'])
def api_add(request):
    return Response({"test": 'abc'})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',                                               
    'rest_framework',
)
```

post.sh

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "name": "Manager",
    "description": "someone who manages"
}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_add/
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`@csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)-decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def api_add(request):
    return Response({"test": 'abc'})
```

**Update:**
If you never need `csrf`-checks, remove the middleware. Seach for `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py` and remove `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',`.

Comment: I have tried that before posting my question. I should have said. I still get the same error.

Comment: I didn't want to switch off CSRF protection as I will have some users posting forms via a web browser and for them I want the CSRF protection. I managed to get it working by updating my urls.py...

Comment: @smithy : An answer explaining exactly the changes you did would be helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Django-Rest-Framework [automatically adds `@csrf_exempt` to all `APIView` (or `@api_view`)](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L373-376).

Only exception is the `SesssionAuthentication` which forces you (correctly) to use CSRF, see the [docs on CSRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors#csrf-protection) or the [DRF source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L125-132)

Comment: OK, but I don't think I'm using SessionAuthentication so why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def add(request):
   ....
```

to:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def add(request):
   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I tried using `@csrf_exempt` but it did not work.

I changed `ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` and it worked for me on local.